# Advices to Improve Carrier Aggregation Matlab Code

Tags: matlab

I'm doing a university project on Carrier Aggregation and I'm using a Matlab code to simulate the process.
There's already a [complete code about Carrier Aggregation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/lte/ug/release-12-downlink-carrier-aggregation-waveform-generation-demodulation-and-analysis.html) in Matlab Library, but when I asked my supervisor about it he told me that I could not use a ready code (Either I write a new one or make an improvement on the existing one).
It could be either an improvement on the code itself or add an additional work beside the [code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/lte/ug/release-12-downlink-carrier-aggregation-waveform-generation-demodulation-and-analysis.html).
I only have a month and a half to complete the project. Any Ideas how to improve it?
Thank you.